# How to properly denote a nuance between comparing choices

Tags: word-choice, nuances, comparative-constructions

My question relates to how to create the nuance between choosing two or more methods and knowing which should be the preferred or more suitable choice.

E.g. 
**"How did you know whether to do/use** 'A' or B?"

＊いつ　Aか、Bどちらが使いますか。

At this point, my Japanese is incredibly limited. So I am making more of an attempt to familiarise myself with different interrogative statements for those times when I have such questions.
Alternatively a different way to say the same in English may have been :

**"When do you do** 'Method A' or 'Method B'? - This when is similar to 'How do you know when'.

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Could you please post a more specific example and how you think it might be translated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

いつ　Aか、Bどちらが使いますか is unnatural.

I say いつAを使い、いつBを使いますか? If you want to emphasize which one you should use, it would be いつAを使い、いつBを使うべきですか?